Где можно задать вопрос о составлении плана изучения языка программирования в свободное от работы время?
С Наступающим! Подскажите, в каких сообществах допустим такой вопрос?

С Наступающим!!! Всех благ!!! В каких то чатах телеграм? И то врятли. Надо понимать, что сколько людей столько и мнений. Так вот когда два разных мнения сталкиваются, происходит холивар...Потому что у каждого план индивидуальный. Я вам советую просто начать...поставьте будильник 30 минут в день, допустим перед ужином...и просто в эти 30 минут делать хоть что то. Читать книгу по выбранному языку/ смотреть ютуб где показывают онлайн код/просто впитывать ...потом понемногу самому начать с минимума. Написать Hello, World . Читать тут вопросы/ответы, читать переписки в группах телеграм по выбраному

Там где преобладают терпимые к разным мнениям люди. А прежде всего вам нужно понять, что именно вы хотите делать с помощью этого языка.
